# SQL Group by statement where value is selected by greatest quantity

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, group-by, max

I apologize in advance if this has already been discussed in a different thread. I did perform several searched but was unable to locate one that would assist me with my needs. 
I have a table that is called t_Item_log. I need to write a query that will pull the data, group by item, sum the total quantities for the item, and select the code that has the greatest qty associated with that item.

**Table Example:**

```
ID  ITEM    CODE    QTY
1   12345    X       1
2   12345    X       2
3   12345    Y       1
4   12345    Z       3
5   6789     X       1
6   6789     X       2
7   6789     Y       1
8   6789     Z       2
9   6789     X       3
10  12345    Y       4
```

**Desired Result**

```
ITEM    CODE    QTY
12345   Y       11
6789    X        9
```

If anyone can point me to a thread that already covered this or provide a foundation for how to write this statement it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated query, because you have to aggregate to get the most common code.  Here is a method that uses a correlated subquery:

```
select ei.item,
       (select top 1 e2.code
        from example as e2
        where e2.item = ei.item
        group by e2.code
        order by count(*) desc, max(e2.id)
       ) as code,
       ei.qty
from (select e.item, sum(e.qty) as qty
      from example as e
      group by e.item
     ) as ei;
```

Note the use of the `max(e2.id)` in the `order by` clause.  In MS Access, `TOP` is really `TOP WITH TIES`.  The inclusion of the `id` guarantees that only one row is returned.

EDIT:

Without a correlated subquery, the calculation is more painful.  Something like this:

```
select e.item, e.qty, i.code
from ((select e.item, sum(e.qty) as qty
       from example as e
       group by e.item
      ) as ei inner join
      (select e.item, max(cnt) as maxcnt
       from (select e.item, e.code, count(*) as cnt
             from example e
             group by e.item, e.code
            ) as ic
       group by e.item
      ) as i
     ) inner join
     (select e.item, e.code, count(*) as cnt
      from example e
      group by e.item, e.code
     ) ic
     on ic.item = i.item and ic.cnt = i.cnt;
```

Comment: Hey guys I keep getting the following error message: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the select statement of the subquery to request only one field"

Comment: @HareM83 . . . That is a very strange error, event that the subquery uses `TOP` and has a stable `ORDER BY` sort.  I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated query :

```
SELECT t.item,
       (SELECT TOP 1 s.code FROM t_Item_log s
        WHERE s.item= t.item
        ORDER BY s.qty DESC) as code_of_max_qty,
       SUM(t.qty)
FROM t_Item_log t
GROUP BY t.item
```

Comment: `LIMIT` should work for MySql, does it also works for ms-access?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try this out.

Comment: @HareM83 Try the fixed query .